# mod_rewrite pass variable and

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

What I would need to do is to pass 1 variable as variable, and the rest as a rest of URL intact, so I can get them by $_GET in php later. The below does not work:

```
RewriteRule     ^store/([a-zA-Z0-9\_\-]+).html?(.*)/?$  store.php?var1=$1&$2 [L]
```

Possible Links could be:

```
store/products.html
store/products.html?sort=asc&price=down
store/products.html?price=down&here_we_can_have_a_lot_of_different_params_in_whatever_order
```

Basically, just take this $var1 and the rest forward to URL? How can I do that?

P.S. I think I found a solution:

```
RewriteRule ^store/([a-zA-Z0-9\_\-]+).html?(.*)/?$  store.php?var1=$1&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
```

Comment: any reason you can't do it directly in php? maybe adding a rewrite condition first would help?

Comment: >any reason you can't do it directly in php? Not sure what you meant by that. I need that URL to be passed in way described above, I am just not too good with mod_rewrite, unfortunately, and googling for answer didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your premise as to how a `RewriteRule` works. A `RewriteRule` *only* matches against the URI path (in apache terms the Request URI) and not against the query string. This means the `(.*)/?$` at the end of your regex only works because it can reduce to just '$' (or the end of the string) and the `?` before it just means the regexp will match `.htm` as well as `.html`

The *simpler* version of your rule is as follows:

```
RewriteRule ^store/([a-zA-Z0-9\_\-]+).html  store.php?var1=$1 [L,QSA]
```

The QSA stands for `Query String Append`, which simply adds back any existing query string to the rewritten URL.